# Javascript make dynamic links but ignore existing links

Tags: javascript

Im using this to dynamically make links in a webpage:

```
var linkWord = function(obj){
  for(i in obj){  
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;   

    var linkStart = '<a href="'+obj[i]+'">';
    var linkEnd = '</a>';
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b(" + i + ")\\b","ig"); 
    x = x.replace(reg, linkStart + i + linkEnd);
    document.body.innerHTML = x;

  }
  console.log(obj);
}

linkWord({
  'The':'http://www.example.com',
  'Vokalia':'http://icant.co.uk',
  'Brent':'http://google.com', 
});
```

This creates links in the page that matches the keyword, but overwrites existing hrefs if it also matches. How can I improve this to ignore the existing links?

No jQuery please.

https://jsfiddle.net/o43Lxmtr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by appending negated sets to the reg expression in order to discard words that are prefixed by `>` and suffixed by `<`.

Edit: A better approach might be to build a **negative lookahead** in order to disallow text contained inside tags.

Edit again: it is even better if the negative lookahead only works for anchor tags:

```
var linkWord = function(obj){
  for(i in obj){  
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;   

    var linkStart = '<a href="'+obj[i]+'">';
    var linkEnd = '</a>';
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b(" + i + ")\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/[a])","ig"); 
    x = x.replace(reg, " " + linkStart + i + linkEnd + " ");
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(obj);
}

linkWord({
  'The':'http://www.example.com',
  'Vokalia':'http://icant.co.uk',
  'behind':'http://google.com', 
});
```

Note that spaces were also added before and after the replaced string since the regex would strip them.

Edit: working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a8t6fz58/).

Edit2: working demo for second solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e3muu6pc/).

Edit3: working demo for third solution [here](https://jsfiddle.net/91zux4ar/).

Comment: This works but if the link contains more than one word it will add a link in a link, eg https://jsfiddle.net/a8t6fz58/3/ any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: Modifying the reg expression you can achieve it. take a look a at this jsfiddle i forked from yours with the working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e3muu6pc/

Comment: I modified the answer to set the new solution for it.

Comment: I modified it again to improve the regex in order to exclude text inside anchor tags only.

Comment: Hi again, I'm having issues with document.body.innerHTML = x;  killing javascript events in the page. What other options do I have other than document.body.innerHTML?

Comment: This is kinda a different question so I started a new one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182108/document-body-innerhtml-killing-events-need-alternate-solution

Answer (score 1):

**It looks like this question was answered before I could come up with a solution, and its also much cleaner than my solution.  Good Job**

> It would seem, after testing your code under various circumstances,
> that the best way to accomplish this is to remove your  links from
> the layout before running your function, and add them again once it is
> completed.
>
> **Keep in mind we are only removing the inner contents of those
> tags, so it will be necessary to store these in order so that they will be added again in the correct places.**

JAVASCRIPT

```
var links_array = {};
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

var linkWord = function(obj){
  for(i in obj){  
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;   
    
    
    var linkStart = '<a class=added href="'+obj[i]+'">';
    var linkEnd = '</a>';
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b(" + i + ")\\b","ig"); 
    x = x.replace(reg, linkStart + i + linkEnd);
    document.body.innerHTML = x;

  }

}
function getPrevLinks(){


for(link in links){
    if(typeof links[link] === 'object'){
    if(! links[link].hasAttribute('class')){
        
    links_array[links[link].innerHTML] = links[link].href;
    links[link].innerHTML = '';
    }
    }
}

return links_array;
}

function returnLinks(links, links_array){
console.log(links);
console.log(links_array);
for(link in links){
    if (links[link].innerHTML === ""){
        for(prop in links_array){
            if(links[link].innerHTML === ""){
                links[link].innerHTML = prop;
                delete links_array[prop];
            }
        }
        
    }
}
        }


getPrevLinks();

linkWord({
  'The':'http://www.example.com',
  'Vokalia':'http://icant.co.uk',
  'Brent':'http://google.com', 
});
returnLinks(links, links_array);
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <p id=me>The Vokalia Brent some more stuff and 
<a href = "http://www.bing.com">The Vokalia Brent 1</a>
<a href = "http://www.bing.com">The Vokalia Brent 2</a>
<a href = "http://www.bing.com">The Vokalia Brent 3</a>
<p>some paragraph</p></p>
<script src="java.js"></script> 
</body>
```

If you need a detailed explanation just leave me a comment.

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdoezrzf/)