# document.body.innerHTML killing events need alternate solution

Tags: javascript

Im using the following code to scan the page for matching words and convert the words into a link.

```
var linkWord = function(obj){
  for(i in obj){  
    var x = document.body.innerHTML;   

    var linkStart = '<a href="'+obj[i]+'">';
    var linkEnd = '</a>';
    var reg = new RegExp("\\b(" + i + ")\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/[a])","ig"); 
    x = x.replace(reg, " " + linkStart + i + linkEnd + " ");
    document.body.innerHTML = x;
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
  }
  console.log(obj);
}

linkWord({
  'The':'http://www.example.com',
  'Vokalia':'http://icant.co.uk',
  'behind':'http://google.com', 
});
```

This works great but document.body.innerHTML is killing other javascript on the page. Can anyone suggest another solution that achieves the same result that doesn't require document.body.innerHTML?

Here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/91zux4ar/

No libraries please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add anchor tags dynamically to a div in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519747/how-to-add-anchor-tags-dynamically-to-a-div-in-javascript)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the answers in that question requires you to know the element type or id to work. My example finds all the matching words in the page and creates the link.

Comment: You append links to the body.

Comment: Dynamically creating links is NOT the issue. The problem is document.body.innerHTML breaking other javascript events.

Comment: The fact that replacing `innerHTML` removes all listeners (which is what I assume you mean by "killing other javascript on the page" is as good a reason as any not to do this kind of wholesale manipulation of the entire DOM as a huge string. Instead, iterate over the DOM and replace the text within each element. You might want to take a look at TreeWalker.

Comment: Thanks, ill check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/91zux4ar/10/

This was a lot of research and work.. but it was worth the result. I think I'll publish it as jquery plugin

```
function wordToLinks(words) {
   function getAllTextNodes(ele) {
    var blackListedElements = ["a", "address", "area", "audio", "base", "br", "button", "canvas", "code", "data", "datalist", "embed", "fieldset", "form", "head", "hr", "html", "iframe", "img", "input", "ins", "keygen", "label", "link", "map", "math", "menu", "menuitem", "meta", "meter", "nav", "noscript", "object", "optgroup", "option", "output", "param", "pre", "progress", "rtc", "ruby", "samp", "script", "select", "source", "style", "svg", "textarea", "time", "title", "track", "var", "video", "wbr", "applet", "basefont", "dir", "font", "isindex", "noframes"];

    var nodes = [];

    (function recrusive(element) {
        var all_nodes = element.childNodes,
            l = all_nodes.length,
            child;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            child = all_nodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 3) {
                nodes.push(child);
            } else if (child.nodeType == 1 && blackListedElements.indexOf((child.tagName).toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                recrusive(child);
            }
        }

    })(ele);
    return nodes.filter(function (e) {
        return (/\w/).test(e.textContent);
    });
}

function createAtag(str, url) {
    var tag = document.createElement('a');
    tag.innerText = str;
    tag.href = url;
    tag.style.display = 'inline';
    return tag;
}

function getIndex(node, word) {
    //return node.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
    var reg = RegExp("\\b(" + word + ")\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/[a])","ig");
    var result = reg.exec(node.nodeValue);
    var index = (result != undefined) ? result.index : -1;
    return index;
}

var all_nodes = getAllTextNodes(document.body);
var w = Object.keys(words);


all_nodes.forEach(function (node) {
    w.forEach(function (word) {
        var c_node = node,
            reg = new RegExp(word, 'i'),
            tag, i;

        i = getIndex(c_node, word);

        while (i > -1) {
            var second = c_node.splitText(i);
            c_node = second.splitText(word.length);
            tag = createAtag(second.nodeValue, words[word])
            second.parentElement.replaceChild(tag, second);
            i = getIndex(c_node, word);
        }
    });
});

}


var words = {
    'the': 'http://www.example.com',
        'Vokalia': 'http://icant.co.uk',
        'behind': 'http://google.com',
};

wordToLinks(words);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work!! But I cant get it to word:( heres a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/91zux4ar/

Comment: Ok - excellent I got it working but found the following: Its not "Global" so it doesn't link all words repeating in the page. It overwrites existing links with a matching word and if there is a match(the) inside a word eg "mother" it will link the like mo<a href="test.com">the</a>r

Comment: I will try make some changes and see if I can figure it out:)

Comment: Im also getting this error in the console -  Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'splitText' on 'Text': The offset 59 is larger than the Text node's length.

Comment: can you give me link to page

Comment: Im testing it using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en so I can see how it behaves on real webpages.

Comment: check out it's working pretty good, but sadly i couldn't get it work for whole words only yet..maybe someone with better regex skills can help

Comment: RegExp("\\b(" + word + ")\\b(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/[a])","ig"), seams to work.

Comment: Awesome it's perfect now

Comment: Updated so "The" will remain "The" and "the" will remain "the" and not become what words object/hash key is.